# Given an amino acid sequence, how to determine the structure (helix, beta sheet etc)?

Tags: amino-acids, protein-structure, protein-folding

Assume there's a short sequence of an amino acids.

```
MAKMGSKKKAGHGGKEKLENMGE
```

I am using molecular structuring softwares to look at secondary structure. But it's blackbox method. In plain theory, how to determine what structure the above peptide will fold into? There must be a basic set of rules, prior to all the complex maths, and modelling?

Based on basic rules I also want to know what and how a different amino acid contributes to the formation specificity.  Will add more details.

Comment: @BryanKrause that's helpful. But what I really want to know why? Like what bonds, interactions of these amino acids contributes to the specificity of forming helix or beta etc. How it is so. I will update my answer. Cheers.

Comment: @benCodigo A lot of that would just be on the wiki pages for those types of structures. eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix#Structure

Comment: Afaik there are no excat rules for this. The methods are based on (known) statistics of the presence / absence of certain amino acids in helices and beta-sheets (e.g. proline and glycine almost never occur in helices)